# Re-using or re-creating lenses with Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have an array. For the sake of an example, it has 81 entries. Of its sublists, 27 are special. Those are its 9 rows, 9 columns, and 9 nonets (All of length 9).

In the following example: `getNonet(3)` returns `[27, 28, 29, 36, 37, 38, 45, 46, 47]`. Which are the indexes in the larger array that describe the 4th nonet;

If I'm using lenses, there are two appraoches I can think of if I want lenses that point to a specific nonet.

```js
const lenses = map(lenseIndex, getNonet(3));
```

or

```js
const pickVals = uncurryN(2, pipe(pick, values));
const allLenses = map(lensIndex, range(0,81));
const lenses = pickVals(getNonet(3), allLenses);
```

Obviously appraoch number 2 is way worse if I'm only using these lenses once. But what about if I'm using and re-using them millions of times. Can I expect much difference in performance by effectively cashing lenses?

---

Does it make sense to create something like this?

```js
const getNonetLenses = memoizeWith(identity,
  compose(map(lenseIndex), getNonet)
);
```

Comment: I assume this is for a Sudoku system of some sort.  I would definitely encourage you to cache your lenses in that case.  Details of how would depend upon how you need to use them.  While a lens is not a heavy-weight object, not caching would spend a number of unnecessary cycles on functions calls in what might be tight loops.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yup. A Sudoku solver. Would you say that memoizeWith is good for that? I'm assuming it just hashes to memory locations (for non-primitives) and returns them?

Comment: `memoizeWith` should be fine, but just as good would be an array of nonet (great word here!) lenses.  Anything should do.   `memoizeWith` does not use a hash, but simply a map of keys to results of the calls.  The function is to allow for instance ``memoizeWith(point => `${point.x}~${point.y}, someExpensivePointFunction)``, since we can't use Objects with anything but String keys, and even Maps don't help us, because their keys are checked only for reference equality.